# how to draw surface with polar coordinate in C#

Tags: c#, ilnumerics, polar-coordinates, surface

I have many points with teta,phy,r.
I want to draw 3D surface in visual C#.
I usually use ILNumerics.
I can draw 3D surface by cartesian coordinate but by polar ...
I have windows form application.
please help me.

Comment: What do you mean you want to draw a 3D surface? Do you want to plot it like a graph or do you want to write a 3D Graphics engine? If it is the later I suggest you do NOT do winforms. Since it would involve writing a software renderer in Win32. Consider using pre-existing Graphics engines like WPF or Unity.

Comment: I have very big project and in a one of my forms I want to show some data in 3D surface.

Comment: In that case get a library to do it. The usual suspects are (in no particular order) Infragistics, Devexpress, Telerik.

Comment: do you know library do this?

Comment: Infragistics, Devexpress, Telerik

Comment: None of those libraries is able to create surface plots? The question is tagged ilnumerics. So th OP seems to request help on their API.

Answer (score 0):

ILNumerics surfaces require their grid points to be defined as [XYZ] tuples. In order to use polar coordinates you must convert your polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates and give these to the ILSurface.

I cannot check right now, but there are conversion functions in ILMath, I think (look for `ILMath.pol2cart()`).

What you require is probably close to a parametric surface: http://ilnumerics.net/non-regular-grids-parametic-surfaces.html